# While mousedown JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, dom-events, onmousedown

I'm trying to run a function while `mousedown` but for the life of me I can't get it to work while holding down but everything works by just clicking. I'm trying to change color of countries on a map as I hold down. 
Here's my code:

```
    var int;
    var mouseStillDown = false;

      function mousedown(geography) 
      {     console.log('mousedown '+mousedownID);
             mouseStillDown = true;
          int = setInterval( performWhileMouseDown(geography), 100);
      }



    function mouseup() 
    {
        clearInterval(int);  
        mouseStillDown = false;
    }

     function mouseout() 
    {
        clearInterval(int);  
    }

      function performWhileMouseDown(geography)
       {
             if (!mouseStillDown)
              {console.log('error');}

            if (mouseStillDown) {
           if(data[geography.id])
            {
              data[geography.id] ++;
            }else
              {
                data[geography.id] = 1;
              }
            var m = {};                                        
            m[geography.id] = color(data[geography.id]);
            map.updateChoropleth(m);
              }

            /* if (mouseStillDown)
              { setInterval(performWhileMouseDown(geography), 100); }*/
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `mousemove` instead, `mousedown` will only fire once.

```
var mouseDown = false;
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { mouseDown = true })
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() { mouseDown = false })
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function() { 
  if (!mouseDown) {
    return;
  }
  // perform while mouse is moving
})
```

Answer (score 0):

here's what worked for me

```
 var timeout ;
function mouseDown(geography){

    timeout = setInterval( function(){


            if(data[geography.id]){

              data[geography.id] ++;
            }else{
              data[geography.id] = 1;
            }
            var m = {};                                        
            m[geography.id] = color(data[geography.id]);
            map.updateChoropleth(m);}, 100);

    return false;
}


function mouseUp(geography){

clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The two conditions for your event are that the code executes every time there is an update in mouse position AND the mouse button is pressed.

Addressing the first part can be done with the 'mousemove' event, which fires when the mouse is moved over the element.

The second filter can be solved, by checking the mouse event, on if the button is pressed. If not, we don't execute the following code.

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function() { // Attach listener
  if (event.buttons == 0)  // Check event for button
    return;                // Button not pressed, exit
  
  // perform while mouse is moving
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I didn't expect this answer to be so active still and thought the code to be self-documenting enough. But for you, the above